# How to query records where jsonb string field is in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb

I want to query `ActiveRecord` collection and select records, where string value inside `jsonb` field is included in a given array.

Model:

```rb
create_table "dishes", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.jsonb     "params"
    ...
end
```

Content of `params` always has this structure:

```rb
{"procart_id"=>"4", "procart_config"=>{}}
```

I have a given array:

```rb
availabilities = ['4', '8', '11']
```

How can I query `Dish` models where `params.procart_id` is in `availabilities` array?

I tried the following:

```rb
Dish.where("params::jsonb ->> 'procart_id' = any (array[?])", availabilities)
```

But it gave me the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: 
: SELECT "dishes".* FROM "dishes" WHERE (params::jsonb ->> 'procart_id' = any (array['4', '8', '11']))
```

Comment: [It works in Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/shCnNANl).

Comment: What version of Postgres and Rails, please?

Comment: @Schwern Postgres 9.4 and Rails 4.2.0

Comment: Those are both *quite* old, but it [does work in Postgres 9.4](https://dbfiddle.uk/l_ibSaA8).

Comment: @Schwern ye, quite old 
Strange, the snippet does really work, but doesn't on my machine.
Maybe I've missed something, will investigate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dish.where("params::jsonb ->> 'procart_id' = any (array[?]::jsonb[])", availabilities)

Try this..it might work

Comment: Removing the `::jsonb[]` after the `any` from this solution worked for me. Ruby 3.2.0, PGSQL 13.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the query params before querying the `Dish` model and query on  `procart_id` like below:

```
availabilities = ['4', '8', '11']
query_params = availabilities.map { |availability| { procart_id: availability } }
Dish.where(params: query_params)
```